# Visual Studio 2015 and MVVM Light

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, mvvm-light

I created a blank Universal App project and wanted to add Mvvm Light to it. But when i go to the solution NuGet Manager and under the tab "Browse" searching for Mvvm Light I get "No packages found".

I installed Mvvm Light in Visual Studio 2015..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your Package Source on your NuGet-Solution manager window. In my new installed Visual Studio 2015, I get the same issue because of the Package Source just provide a Microsoft and .NET.  So we need add the nuget.org into the NuGet Package Source list through the setting icon behind the Package source combobox on NuGet-Solution manager page.
[image]

Then choose the Package source as nuget.org in the combobox and then searching Mvvm Light again, it will be found under that package source.

**Update:**

Please add the package source as below screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Well I tried that but it gives an error: "The Remote name could not be resolved: 'packagesource'. I added a screenshot.

Comment: I have added a screenshot about how to set the package source in NuGet Package Manager configure window.

Comment: Yes indeed, when I started a new project Package source was auto on nuget.org for some reason.